# How to feeding Crystal Report 8.5 parameters from VB6.0 Application?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, parameters

How to feeding Crystal Report 8.5 parameters from VB6.0 Application?

Comment: Please provide some more information. Are you loading the report in a ReportViewer control inside a VB6 GUI? Are you trying to open the report externally in Crystal Reports?

Comment: Thank you for your comment....Yes I  load the report in a Crystal report viewer control inside a VB6....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it (assuming that crxRpt points to a valid report object):

```
Dim crxParam as CRAXDRT.ParameterField
For Each crxParam In crxRpt.ParameterFields
    Select Case crxParam.Name
        Case "{?MyStringParam1}"
            crxParam.AddCurrentValue "Parameter1 value"
        Case "{?MyNumberParam2}"
            crxParam.AddCurrentValue 25.35
    End Select
Next crxParam
```

Comment: Heather,
Thank you but I still have some problem while executing my report. let's  explain it :
I have made a new report using Crystal Reports 8.5 (report1) which uses a stored procedure for its data source.
The stored procedure has 2 input parameters (@p1 and @p2) and when I enter some test data for @p1 and @p2, every thing is all right.
Then, I added the report1 in visual basic 6.0 IDE and added a new form (form1) and a crystal report viewer control on form1.
Now please help me: I wanna to show the report1.
What codes exactly should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetItemByName(ByVal Name As String, Optional ByVal SubreportName As Object = Nothing) As CRAXDDRT.ParameterFieldDefinition method.  Once you have the ParameterFieldDefinition object, the world is your oyster.

Answer (score 0):

here is the way to pass parameters to RPT via CRviewer

```
Set Report = Appl.OpenReport(App.Path & "MyReport.rpt")
CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report

Report.Database.Tables.Item(1).SetLogOnInfo CnDNS, CnDB, CnUser, CnPwd
Report.EnableParameterPrompting = True
Report.DiscardSavedData
Report.ParameterFields(1).ClearCurrentValueAndRange
Report.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue ParameterValue1
Report.ParameterFields(2).ClearCurrentValueAndRange
Report.ParameterFields(2).AddCurrentValue ParameterValue2
Report.ParameterFields(3).ClearCurrentValueAndRange
Report.ParameterFields(3).AddCurrentValue ParameterValue3
```